# Display XML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Here's my sample XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry n="5">
<form type="lemma">hi
    <orth xml:lang="syc">ܐܳܐܱܪ</orth>
</form>

<gramGrp>
    <gram type="pos">noun</gram>
    <gram type="gender">commonGender</gram>
</gramGrp>

<etym>
    <lang>Greek</lang>
    <mentioned>ἀήρ</mentioned>
</etym>     

<form type="inflected" ana="#n_pl">
    <orth xml:lang="syc">ܐܰܐܷܪ̈ܰܣ</orth>
</form>

<sense>
    <cit type="translation" xml:lang="en">
        <quote>air, breeze</quote>
    </cit>
</sense>
</entry>
```

I need to display this in a formatted fashion, depending on the tags.  I've followed the code as found at w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp, changing the filename and TagName values as necessary.  In the end... nothing happens, just a blank screen.  I do have a server from which I am running this, btw.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
    }   
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "dict.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("lemma")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("sense")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

I will worry about getting all the formatting correct and all the tags represented afterwards, I just need to get it working at all, first.

Comment: Could you check the console for errors/success messages?

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I didn't even know there was a console on FF that could detect JS until now!

Comment: Before you write too much of that HTML generation code, take an hour or so and read about HTML templating, for example with http://handlebarsjs.com/. This can save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're calling `loadXMLDoc`, or defining the `xml` variable, or calling `myFunction`.